# How to convert string to boolean in php

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

I've defined this function in php

```
function ifstatement($statement = 'if(10 > 9;1+1;2+2)') {
// $statement = str_replace(' ', '', $statement);

if (strpos($statement, 'if(') > -1) {
   $statement = rtrim(ltrim(str_replace(' ', '', $statement), 'if('), ')');
   $exp = explode(';', $statement);
  if ( $exp[0] ) {
    if (strpos($exp[1], 'if(' )> -1) {
     return ifstatement($exp[1]);
    } else {
     return 1;
   }
  } else {
  if (strpos($exp[2], 'if(')> -1) {
    return ifstatement($exp[2]);
  } else {
   return 0;
  }
 }
}else{
  echo 'out';
  }
}
```

the problem is the function always return 1 even if the condition in the if statement in the function argument is false which is tested with

```
if($exp[0])
```

it looks like the `$exp[0]` comes as a string, how can i convent this to be tested as if argument

Comment: What on Earth are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: am trying to create function that allow users to use if statement to compare two value specified(i.e 10 and 9 for this case) in their form, $statement is the string am expecting from database..

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do here, you approach is all wrong. I just tried to re-write this in a way that makes sense to me and I can't, because it just doesn't. Please outline exactly what you are trying to achieve, and maybe we can give you some pointers.

Comment: I've a form with multiple field including the text input where the user specifies the logic statement(IF() statement), the statement is stored in the db and during viewing information some calculation has to be done basing of the logic statement specified..the string $statement is what stored in database..hope its clear now..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$exp[0]` contains `10 > 9` (whatever you have before first `;`), so it will evaluate to false only it it's an empty string or `'0'`. To properly evaluate this you should use the [`eval()`](http://php.net/eval) function:

```
$condition = '10 > 9';
$result = eval('return ' . $condition . ';');
```

> Note: don't ever use `eval()` in production environment unless you are **really** sure that your input is harmless and you can't do it another way.

Comment: eval? That if is not a PHP if even. And please do not that easily suggest to use eval. Seriously, eval is not for production use.

Comment: You are right, it's dangerous, But in this case only eval() will work, unless he writes a lot of code for proper parsing of conditions or narrows down possible expressions. (anyway, added warning to my answer)

Comment: PHP is not able to `eval` thw following code: `IF(cond;true;false)`, even if you prefer `eval` over writing a parser on your own, using `eval` is not a solution here.

Comment: what could be the solution @harke, am trying to exract the condition from $statement so that i can use it in if statement.. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: But `$result = eval('return cond;')` will work. In this case it's eval or some custom lexer+parser.

Comment: The other solution is to parse your condition into a syntax tree and then execute the syntax tree. Or at least first parse it into it's parts and then work with those. @Crack: But `'return cond;'` was not asked for. It's asked for `if(10 > 9;1+1;2+2)`. If you take that as `cond`, eval does not work: [Demo](http://codepad.org/KiReKDOr)

Comment: Oops, it seems we are talking about different parts of the code. I meant to propose eval for evaluating condition, not entire _if_ expression.

Comment: @crack: As it can be seen in the code, there can be an `IF` inside an `IF`: Part of the condition itself can be another `IF`. So `10>9` could be `IF(1;2;3)`. Eval can't do it - oh wait, only the results can be a subexpression, now I see it.

Comment: Hmm, well, that does not make a difference, fails with splitting the parameters apart, so eval can only solve a very limited fraction of the overall problem. Please elaborate your answer so it actually can match the OPs need, eval alone is not the solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$exp[0] = (boolean) $exp[0];
```

is probably the thing you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

Unless you're going to do this properly (with a parser), you're better off making users specify their conditions in multiple fields. One row would have a text field for `x`, a select field for comparison operator (`==`,`<`,`>`), and another text field for `y`. Then they can specify whether to match all checks or any checks. When they're broken out like this you'll be able to execute the intended logic without having to implement a new language using `strpos` and `eval`, which is total madness.

You can see examples of this type of interface in Thunderbird's message filter editing:

[image]

and in iTune's smart playlist editing:

[image]